# One website on two domains

Tags: iis, redirect, seo, hosting

I have 2 domains:

www.first.com

www.second.com

Lets assume that In the first one I have an online store, at the second one I have only products of this store (seperate applications that running on the server).

The products link is

www.second.com/firstProduct

www.second.com/secondProduct

www.second.com/thirdProduct

and etc...

I want to redirect users to the first website when someone hit www.second.com, ie not the full product path.

What redirect should I use? 301? In terms of SEO what is the best approach?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the 301 Moved Permanently, is the code you want to return for this redirect.  Search engines typically will queue up 301's for updates to their results, as this indicates that the resource will now be found at the new url, and that the old one is soon to be obsolete.

In your case, since you never want www.second.com/ to be accessed directly, the 301 is exactly what you want.

You might also consider adding a robots.txt file with allow + disallow statements in there, as most of the bots you actually care about for SEO will honor it.